# How to reuse a passed reference in some other member-function of a class?

Tags: c++, reference

I have a very odd requirement. I have two member functions of my class which receive reference of different objects each (but the two objects are related by inheritance). Now I want to be able to use these two different types references (depending on use-case, I will get only one, but never both together) in some other member function of my class. How to achieve this. I know this sounds a bit of an oddity, but the instance of my class is going to be used as a plug-in to some other process and I "have-to" derive my class from the pure virtual class that the process framework owns and override those two member-functions I just mentioned. Is there any way for this?

To illustrate this scenario:

```
func1(const Data& params, MyParent& parent);
func2(const Data& params, MyChild& child);
```

Above are the two member-functions that I have to override and there is no I can change the pattern of invocation and I have to live with these non-const references

Is there any way to let's say call `myfunc()` with either `MyParent& parent` or `MyChild& child`, but never both? I don't want to call `myfunc()` directly from `func1()` and `func2()`, as I want some processing to be done in between and then I want to queue up all my to-be-done tasks after all the processing and finally call `myfunc()` with either `MyParent& parent` or `MyChild& child`, but never both.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ there is function or method [overloading](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions2/). You should simply declare your method with both types and compiler will chose which should be executed:

```
myfunc(MyParent& parent);
myfunc(MyChild& child);
```

Comment: I know I can use overloaded functions. But, what if I have some 15 such `myfunc()`? That would mean I need to write 30.

Comment: Yes, you will have to. You could try to do some awful design with `std::variant` at your own responsibility, but I would not recommend that.

Comment: Templates.
template <class MyParentOrChild>
void myfunc(MyParentOrChild& parentOrChild) {}